# Distribution Certificate issue

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I am a new developer within a team and I have had to takeover a previous developers application.

The app has been rejected several times and is now in a stable position to be resubmitted.

The issue is that XCode is not able to validate the signature because I do not have the private keys installed.

Is there any resolution to this - my first instinct was to delete the app from iTunes Connect and start again but it is warning me that I will not be able to reuse the same name!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of choices:

1. Revoke the distribution certificate in the provisioning portal of the iOS Dev Center. Then create a new one using a certificate request generated on your machine. You can then update your App Store provisioning profile to use the new certificate.
2. Export the public and private key pair from the previous developer's machine if available. (From within Keychain Access). Install them on your machine and the existing profile should work.

I'm guessing option 1 is the best in your circumstances.

Comment: I was hoping to not have to revoke the certificate but that was the only option. Thanks very much for your help